# How to make blog network like SmashingMagazine

Tags: wordpress, networking, blogs

I noticed SmashingMagazine released a Smashing Network feature, which includes other website's posts. This is interesting, I am wondering how do they do that?

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/network-posts/

B.T.W. I am using Wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just RSS: [FeedWordPress | simple and flexible Atom/RSS syndication for WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) or [WordPress › SimplePie Plugin for WordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/) (or other plugins) and their own CSS, etc., for presentation.